# move superposed elements in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm strugguling to make my javaFX program fonctionnal. I'd like some advice.

There is a drawing of what I have done:

[image: organisation]

The screen is a set of images (The little rectangles).

My goal is to put a card on the top when it is clicked.

[image: goal]

To do so, i've set the principal contener as a StackPane.
I've thought about putting the cards directly into the StackPane but it seems that the setLayoutX and setLayoutY methods don't seem to move my images.

The solution I came out with is putting in my StackPane multiples AnchorPane (one for each card). Each AnchorPane has the size of the StackPane contener,
and contains a sigle card. Like that, I can set the position of each card.

[image: widgets]

My problem with this method is the following : because each AnchorPane has the size of the principal conteneur, the AnchorPane that contains the last card
is placed in front of the pther AnchorPanes.

Consequently, when I click on my last card, I works perfectly, but I can't click the other cards because there is a invisible Node in front of them.

It would be very nice if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: `StackPane` manages the layout of its components, so the layout coordinates you set won't matter. I don't really understand the purpose of the `AnchorPanes`. Just use a regular `Pane`, and set the layout coordinates of the cards. If you can't make it work, create and post a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example.

[image: example]

Click on each of the cards to play them.  After all of the cards are played, the game will reset when the clicks anywhere on the playing table.  Then a new hand will be dealt to the player.

It uses placeholders for empty card positions on the playing table.

For layout, it uses a VBox for the playing table and an HBox for the cards in hand.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class CardApp extends Application {
    private static final int NUM_CARDS = 5;

    private HBox hand;
    private VBox table;
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        scene = new Scene(deal());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Parent deal() {
        List<Card> cards =
                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, NUM_CARDS)
                        .mapToObj(Card::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        Collections.shuffle(cards);

        hand = new HBox(20,
                cards.toArray(new Card[0])
        );

        table = new VBox(30,
                new CardPlaceholder(),
                hand
        );
        table.setStyle("-fx-background-color: mintcream;");
        table.setPadding(new Insets(30));

        // click on cards to play them.
        for (Card card: cards) {
            card.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                playCard(card, hand, table);

                // when all cards are played, click anywhere to re-deal on a new table.
                if (hand.getChildren().stream().noneMatch(c -> c instanceof Card)) {
                    table.setOnMouseClicked(me -> scene.setRoot(deal()));
                }
            });
        }

        return table;
    }

    private void playCard(Card card, HBox hand, VBox table) {
        int index = hand.getChildren().indexOf(card);
        hand.getChildren().set(index, new CardPlaceholder());
        table.getChildren().set(0, card);
        card.setOnMouseClicked(null);
    }

    static class Card extends StackPane {
        public Card(int value) {
            Rectangle background = new Rectangle(55, 80, Color.LIGHTSTEELBLUE);
            background.setStroke(Color.LIGHTSTEELBLUE.darker());
            background.setStrokeWidth(3);
            background.setArcWidth(15);
            background.setArcHeight(15);

            Label foreground = new Label("" + value);
            foreground.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 30; -fx-text-fill: rgb(60,63,74);");

            getChildren().setAll(background, foreground);
        }
    }

    static class CardPlaceholder extends StackPane {
        public CardPlaceholder() {
            Rectangle background = new Rectangle(
                    55, 80,
                    Color.SILVER.deriveColor(
                            0,1,1, .4
                    )
            );

            background.setStroke(
                    Color.SILVER.deriveColor(
                            0,1,1, .6
                    )
            );
            background.setStrokeWidth(3);
            background.setArcWidth(15);
            background.setArcHeight(15);
            background.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(10d, 5d);

            getChildren().setAll(background);
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity in answering this limited question, everything is in one file.  For a more substantial app, the game logic and game model would be separated from the UI (using MVC), the layout might be done in FXML and styling would be done via CSS.