# JavaFX, stop central node from filling gap when right node gets removed

Tags: javafx

I'm making a dashboard in JavaFX using SceneBuilder.

I'm using a BorderPane: on the left side, there are buttons, that when pressed load nodes inside the center of the pane.
But the nodes loaded in the center also could have buttons, that when pressed load an additional node inside the right side of the pane.

This additional right node could also be removed by pressing a button, but when this happens, the node in the center of the pane stretches all the way to the right to fill the space. I looked at the documentation and this is normale behaviour: the center node of the pane automatically fills every void space.

How can i do this? I'm only working through SceneBuilder. This is my FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.ratatouille23.View.HomepageView">
   <left>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="306.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="18.0" layoutY="279.0" prefHeight="421.0" prefWidth="277.0" stylesheets="@homepage.css">
               <styleClass>
                  <String fx:value="nav-2" />
                  <String fx:value="shadow" />
               </styleClass>
               <children>
                  <Button layoutX="19.0" layoutY="21.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickPulsanteInserisciAvvisi" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="240.0" styleClass="nav-btn" stylesheets="@homepage.css" text="Inserisci Avvisi" />
                  <Button fx:id="buttonPersonalizzaMenu" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="89.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickPulsantePersonalizzaMenu" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="240.0" styleClass="nav-btn" stylesheets="@homepage.css" text="Personalizza Menu" />
                  <Button fx:id="buttonCreaUtente" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="158.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickPulsanteCreaUtente" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="240.0" styleClass="nav-btn" stylesheets="@homepage.css" text="Crea Utente" />
                  <Button layoutX="23.0" layoutY="372.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="41.0" styleClass="signout" stylesheets="@homepage.css">
                     <graphic>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="SIGN_OUT" size="2em" wrappingWidth="20.861303329467773" />
                     </graphic>
                  </Button>
                  <Label layoutX="75.0" layoutY="372.0" text="Log out">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Al Nile" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="18.0" prefHeight="253.0" prefWidth="277.0" stylesheets="@homepage.css">
               <children>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="USER" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="63.0" size="60" />
                  <Label layoutX="78.0" layoutY="90.0" text="Benvenuto," textFill="WHITE">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Tahoma" size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="labelUsername" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="124.0" text="UTENTE" textFill="WHITE">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Al Nile" size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
               <styleClass>
                  <String fx:value="shadow" />
                  <String fx:value="nav-1" />
               </styleClass>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <top>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="1100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="343.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
         </padding></AnchorPane>
   </right>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="453.0" scaleShape="false" snapToPixel="false" stylesheets="@homepage.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <padding>
            <Insets right="30.0" />
         </padding></AnchorPane>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="1102.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Why are you using `AnchorPane`s and maually positioning so many of the controls, instead of using [standard layout techniques](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)? If you don't want the center component to full the space, don't use a `BorderPane` (as you noted that is precisely the documented behavior of a `BorderPane`). Use, e.g., a `HBox` and configure it so the left and center nodes cannot grow beyond their preferred sizes.

Comment: The anchorpanes on the left side don't give me problems and i need them for an absolute layout, but yeah, the center and right ones are wrong. Still, i asked this because changing the border panes would mean changing all of my code, so i thought it was an option i could set or unset. Anyway, if that's not the case, i'll do it. Thanks

Comment: From what i got from this site, anchorpanes should almost never be used. The ones you see here on the right and center were used because i was trying to not make the center pane stretch to the right. In fact, when i load a node in the center pane, given the center and right anchorpanes i used, it actually has the size i want, but when i load a node into the right pane and remove it, the center node stretches to the right. I said they are wrong because i used them just for this, and it surely is not good practice. Now that i removed them, the center pane stretches from the beginning.

Comment: You exactly got my point, i was using them as placeholders. I will probably do like you said, i was worried it was too bad of a practice, but still...

Comment: I would use [`ikonli`](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/) over `Fontawesome`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I really don't like fontawesome, but was the first thing i found and used (with a lot of troubles).

Answer (score 1):

> stop central node from filling gap when right node gets removed

If everything works as you want when there is a node there of a certain size and doesn't when you remove that node, then instead of removing the node, either [set it's visibility](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible(boolean)) to false, or replace it with an empty placeholder node of exactly the same size.

The optimal solution is to use correct layout panes and constraints rather than anchors and hardcoding, but the suggested fix may be sufficient for you.

Unnecessary hardcoding of sizes and absolute fixing of positions is a bad practice. But using the spring/strut concept, *when needed*, is ok. Empty placeholder nodes are also reasonable. [TableView uses a placeholder for no content](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#placeholderProperty) as does this [card layout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74659481/move-superposed-elements-in-javafx/74662493#74662493).

See [strut and springs](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javafxbest2.html) for info on using placeholder nodes to influence layout.  The linked article includes obsolete builder code but the concept is still relevant.  An alternate approach is to use padding or margin settings for nodes via constraint settings on the nodes or layout managers.  Which approach is best to use can vary on a case-by-case basis.  For a case where you want to remove a panel but still have it take up space, either using a placeholder node of the same size and constraints, or setting the nodes visibility property to false, is usually the best approach.